# I look forward to a resubmission or I look forward for your resubmission

Tags: word-choice

Which is one correct of the above sentence?
OR 
Can I say' I'm looking forward for your resubmission or I'm looking forward to your resubmission

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ell stack Exchange.

We don't use the preposition "for" after "look forward".
Instead, you use "to". You look forward to something or doing something. For examples:

I look forward to your visit.

I look forward to seeing you soon.

So "I am looking forward to a/your resubmission" is correct.

Comment: Your statement is not entirely true. If the phrase is being used literally rather than figuratively, it's possible: *I've been tied to this chair. I will **look forward for** hours.*